# Git diff for branches’ starting point

Tags: git

Assuming I'm on branch `foo`, I use `git difftool main`.

If I pull `main` to the latest, then that diff changes. However, if push up the PR to GitHub I see the diff I expect.

What is the command to say `git difftool main-at-the-SHA-where-I-started-this-branch`?

Comment: Take a look at `main`'s local reflog (with `git reflog main`). If no other operations happened on the branch other than the pull you described, you should find current SHA (after the pull) referenced `main{0}`, the previous SHA (the one you look for) should then be `main@{1}`, and so on for older positions of the local branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to view locally the same diff as the one you see in your PR, you need to run :

```sh
git difftool main...foo  # 3 dots, not a typo
```

---

The 3 dots notation for git diff is [explained in the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) :

> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`. You can omit any one of `<commit>`, which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.

It will show you the diff of your branch since it forked from `main` -- as opposed to the diff between your branch and the current state of `main`, which may change if other branches are merged.

Comment: actually i just tried this in another place and it did not work – any idea why? im getting a massive diff

Comment: run `git log --graph --oneline a...b` and check if the list of commits you see is the one you expect. Run `git log --graph --oneline a b` (no dots) to have a complete view of both branches.